# Spark : Difference between repartitionByRange by column and repartitionByRange by list of values of same column

Tags: apache-spark

I have seen 2 scenarios for partitioning data in spark -

```
df.repartitionByRange(n, col(columnName))
```

and

```
df.repartitionByRange(n, List(col(ColumnName):_*))
```

How does above two work internally ?
what is the difference between both ?

Comment: both are same. calling the same method with different semantics doesn't change the internal functionality.

Comment: @SomeshwarKale I am getting performance gain by the second one.

Comment: but you are calling the same method. this shouldn't happen

Comment: can you explain me how will it work, I am bit new to the performance optimization and partitioning in spark